# How can I route all my Internet usage through a remote server?

Tags: linux, routing, privacy

I have a remote Red Hat Linux server in [Hong Kong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong) with rackspace with root access.

At home I have a regular [ADSL2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.992.3) 100 Mbit/s connection using a [FRITZ!Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FRITZ!Box).

I would like to understand the ways of browsing anonymously so that my ISP cannot actually see what we are looking at, essentially so that our Red Hat Linux server is encrypting all pages we look at.

1. What is this called?
2. How does one go about it?
3. Does this sort of thing chew up a tonne of server resources?

I would imagine I need a Unix server at my end as well (I've got a [MacBook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook) and Mac tower)

Ideally, I would like to be able to do this with my Mac laptop when I'm travelling knowing that I am browsing the web privately.

Comment: I think you really should be using something like OpenVPN. Setup an OpenVPN service on your Hong Kong server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a proxy server. There are several ways to set one up, but I use an encrypted SOCKS proxy personally. See [this awesome Lifehacker tutorial](http://lifehacker.com/237227/geek-to-live--encrypt-your-web-browsing-session-with-an-ssh-socks-proxy) for information on how to set one up. The great thing about this method is that no additional software is necessary, as it just tunnels through a SSH connection.

I run a proxy server for myself and a few friends, and it doesn't chew up much in the way of RAM or CPU cycles. It will obviously take up network resources, as it has to fetch pages and send them back to the client.

Comment: I've been doing it this way for a few months now and it works splendidly.

Comment: Your link only describes tunneling traffic from the web browser, not all traffic.

Answer (score 1):

You could install [**Squid proxy**](http://www.squid-cache.org/) on your remote Linux server and connect to it using **HTTPS**, by using the proxy server settings in the configuration options of your browser.

It does not use a lot of server resources (just a bit of CPU time).

If it is not possible to connect to the proxy using HTTPS (it's not something I have tried), you could connect to the Squid proxy on the Linux server through a VPN, like [**OpenVPN**](http://openvpn.net/).

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I am looking into Squid proxy. cheers!

Comment: @cosmicbdog: Tunnelling through SSH, as tapped-out mentioned, would be easier than using OpenVPN.  Also, polipo is an alternative to squid, which is a little easier to setup.

Comment: Cheers @paradroid - I think I have set it up now tunneling via SSH. How can I be sure? Actually - I just went to what is my ip and i now have the ip address of my server. Very cool. Cheers!

Comment: @cosmicbdog: You should select the other answer instead, seeing as you went for that solution.  Cheers.